# Match EOF token in lexer rule Antlr4

Tags: java, token, antlr, antlr4, eof

I want to match `EOF` token in lexer rules for Antlt4, but it does not work:

```
RULE:    EOF;
```

After an input of an **empty** text file the lexer recognizes only one token `RULE` that is right

**However**, if I try to do such a thing:

```
WORD:    'word';
RULE:    EOF;
```

and this input file:

```
word
```

I got `WORD` in a list of recognized tokens by lexer.

Who can explain why it is so and how to match `EOF` by `RULE`-rule in such a case?

(in the 2nd input file I have no characters after a *"word"*-string

Comment: The fact that the input source `word` produces a `WORD` token given the grammar `WORD:    'word'; RULE:    EOF;` seems right. I think I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The use of EOF in the lexer grammar is undefined. You are probing around code that doesn't check EOF in lexer. EOF is hardwired to -1. EOF appears as the last token in the stream, even with your "working" example. `RULE` is assigned a positive value and can't be reassigned as -1 for an alias in the tokens file--it's clobbered generating a lexer--and there is no way to assign a token value with `tokens { ... }` syntax. "Normal" tokens are assumed to be positive token values. Instead, define a parser rule for "word: WORD EOF", and include a semantic predicate to demand the tokens be sequential.